# Как заставить Flask не возвращать ничего на запрос?

Tags: python, flask

В Nginx есть возможность ничего не вернуть на запрос - `return 444;`

А вот как сделать подобную штучку во Flask - не понятно. Знаю, что 444 - фича конкретно nginx. но должен же быть способ реализовать подобное на Flask.

Собственно, вопрос. Как реализовать во Flask невозврат на запрос?

**UPD:** да, я знаю, что остутствие ответа - иногда плохо и ля-ля, но это именно то, чего я хочу.

Comment: Вообще ничего? Или все-таки ответ с пустым контентом? `return '', 204`

Comment: Вопрос стоял четко: игнорировать, как сообщения бывшего. Забыть и не вспоминать. Ничего не отвечать. Включить режим "Меня тут нет". Надеюсь, понятно изложил мысли =-D

Comment: Так у вас перед Flask всё равно какой-то сервер стоит же?

Comment: Нет, интересует конкретно Flask в чистых полевых условиях без посредников

Comment: Что значит "не возвращать"? Чтобы получатель ждал и отвалился по таймауту в итоге?

Comment: Меня устраивает то, как работает 444 в nginx - "закрывает" соединение без отправки данных. Реализация может быть любая. Цель - ничего не вернуть.

Comment: Отправляйте ответ 403, для клиентов он адекватнее работает. https://habr.com/ru/post/415565/

Comment: Я уже четко дал понять, что мне нужен не 403, а отсутсвие ответа =-/ 
Как будто на марсианском пишу

Comment: В WSGI не предусмотрена возможность закрыть соединение, соответственно во Flask этого добиться невозможно.

Comment: @WhiteApfel отсутствие ответа приведет к ошибке 503 по таймауту

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, То, что произойдёт у кого-то где-то там - не особо важно. Суть - не возвращать ничего

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров смотря как разорвано соединение.

Comment: Когда это у вас браузер научился wsgi?